# Изменение константы

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Непонятен синтаксис

```
procedure MikuInit( const Sprite : zglPSprite2D );
begin
   Sprite.X := 800 + random( 800 );
   Sprite.Y := random( 600 - 128 );
   zgl_GetMem( Sprite.Data, SizeOf( zglTPoint2D ) );
   with zglTPoint2D( Sprite.Data^ ) do
   begin
  X := -random( 10 ) / 5 - 0.5;
  Y := ( random( 10 ) - 5 ) / 5;
      end;
  end;
```

Объясните, почему константный параметр, объявленный в процедуре как константный, меняется внутри неё. Написано на FreePascal. Почему кстати нет метки FreePascal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пометка `const` в данном случае говорит о том, что структура, при передаче в функцию не копируется, а передаётся по ссылке, тем не менее, в отличии от `var` - ссылка как бы защищённая, то есть вы не можете написать такой код:

```
Sprite:= NewSprite;
```

Однако, эта "защита" касается самого `Sprite`, но не касается его полей.
То есть, в данном случае, вы не можете поменять одну структуру на другую, но саму структуру менять никто не запрещает.

Так как возникли разногласия, уточню свой, возможно, не совсем корректный ответ. Сказанное характерно, если в качестве параметра передаётся PRecord, то есть переменная типа указатель на `record`. Обычно они помечаются префиксом P, в отличии от самих рекордов, которые помечаются префиксом T.

В нашем примере используется `zgl`**P**`Sprite2D`, что скорее всего указатель (иначе было бы `zgl`**T**`Sprite2D`).

В случае `zgl`**T**`Sprite2D` код действительно не компилируется.

Comment: Пройдите по первой ссылке в моем ответе.

Comment: возьмите модуль отсюда:

http://zengl.googlecode.com/svn-history/r928/trunk/src/zgl_sengine_2d.pas

и эта функция у вас скомпилируется.

Можно подумать, что типы данных задаются в pascal только как у вас в примере...

Comment: К сожалению, в ответ @karmadro4 добавить комментарий не выходит, добавлю тут.

Вторую ссылку прочитал, про уменьшение размера стека там также написано.

Насчёт логической венгерки... Ну а что ещё могло иметься в виду под zglPSprite2D? Зачем тогда там P, если не для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, что это указатель?

PRecord автоматически разыменовывается и ведёт себя как TRecord, так что... Впрочем утверждать не буду, надо смотреть ассемблер, а это того не стоит.

Comment: Я думаю, что раз ОП удовлетворен ответом, то и ладно. Вот [здесь](http://free-pascal-general.1045716.n5.nabble.com/How-to-Copy-a-Record-data-to-a-buffer-td2818210i60.html) знакомые всё лица обсуждают автоматическое разыменование.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что структуры константами не бывают.

Там максимум фиксируется адрес указателя.

То есть напрямую  `zglPSprite2D:= zglPSprite2DNEW;` может и не даст,а менять атрибуты - всегда пожалуйста.

А оно у вас вообще компилится? ))

Comment: Не представляю, тогда зачем автор в данном случае использовал это. Программа совсем коротенькая, это пример использования одной фичи в   2D движке.

Comment: Млин да. Облажался))

Спишем на то, что паскаль я не видел с первого курса или это причуды местного зверька)

Comment: @SilverIce, а зачем тогда гадаете? :( Я в сомнениях, поставить ли минус или нет, последняя правка совершенно неценная.

Answer (score 2):

Преобразовано из комментария, чтобы дать возможность удалить неправильный ответ.

Этот пример нерабочий.

- [Код не компилируется](http://ideone.com/J5Dp5)
- [Противоречит контракту `const`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu58.html#x156-16600014.4.4)

Из логики этой процедуры явственно следует, что параметр по ссылке должен быть объявлен как `var`. Почему автор примера неряшливо объявил его как `const` для меня остается загадкой.

Comment: код не компилируется так:

    type zglPSprite2D = record
      X, Y: Integer;
      Data: Pointer;
    end;
 
    type zglTPoint2D = record
      X, Y: Real;
    end;
но вполне компилируется так:

    type
      zglPSprite2D = ^zglTSprite2D;
      zglPSEngine2D = ^zglTSEngine2D;

      zglTSEngine2D = record
        Count : LongWord;
        List  : array of zglPSprite2D;
      end;

      zglTSprite2D = record
        X, Y    : Single;
        Data    : Pointer;
      end;

    type zglTPoint2D = record
      X, Y: Real;
    end;

Comment: Он компилируется потому, что вы объявили указатель и навелосипедили с его помощью передачу параметра по ссылке, а далее пользуетесь автоматическим разыменованием указателей на структурированные типы.  Какой теперь смысл `const` в этом объявлении?

Comment: Это не я объявил и не я навелосипедил, это конкретный фрагмент кода из сети, в комментарии на мой ответ ссылка на него.

В реальной жизни такой приём используется постоянно, например для вызовов функций из Dll.

Зачем так написали - вопрос не ко мне, я отвечал на то, что спросили.

Как вариант, const могли использовать для того, чтобы в место вызова вместо рекорда не могли вернуть мусор.

Comment: > сэкономить 4 байта в стэке

Передача фактического параметра по ссылке эквивалентна передаче по значению указателя на этот параметр. В случае передачи параметра-указателя по ссылке (**константный указатель на указатель**) не вижу никакой экономии.

> В реальной жизни такой приём используется постоянно, например для вызовов функций из Dll
Нет никакого смысла городить матрешки из указателей и не использовать их.

Comment: без ключевого слова const, адрес указателя копируется в стэке, это как раз 4 байта.

Using const allows the compiler to optimize code for structured- and string-type parameters. (из справки Delphi)

я не за сомнительные оптимизации, но использование слова const при прочих равных предпочтительней для строк и структур.

Чтобы закончить тему напомню, что вопрос был: "почему значение меняется", а не зачем кто-то написал кривой, по вашему мнению, код.

Comment: Код не компилируется

и собственно, с чего всё началось, код компилируется, а вы привели пример, где кто-то этот код пытался неправильно использовать, причем при этом умудрился нарушить негласное соглашение об именовании типов в ObjectPascal.

Вообще говоря, вы всё ещё считаете свой ответ правильным?

Comment: > из справки Delphi

Почитайте ремарку про `const` в документации fpc (вторая ссылка)

> нарушить негласное соглашение об именовании

*Негласное* довольно сложно нарушить. Если вы про **логическую венгерку**, принятую в сырцах библиотек Delphi, то она уже нарушена неймспейс префиксом `zgl`

> использование слова const при прочих равных предпочтительней для строк и структур

Указатели не входят с этот список.